# Possible to use different learning rate for different neuron in Keras/Tensorflow?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, keras, training

The simplest example is to have faster/slower learning rates in the upper/lower layers of a network. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945554/how-to-set-layer-wise-learning-rate-in-tensorflow) on tensorflow.

- Is there a similar trick in Keras?
- Going one step further, can we set different learning rates for specific range/set of neurons/weights in a particular layer?

Comment: Couldn't write this as a comment, sorry. You can follow this thread here: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/3004 Seems at least that the layer-wise tuning should come.

Comment: @ChristianSafka Nice! though still some issues but I will see if I could make it work

Comment: @ChristianSafka You could make your comment above an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this thread here: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/3004 Seems at least that the layer-wise tuning should come.

Comment: The pull request is closed by now. You can find the new one here: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5920 Until then, depending on your problem, it might be helpful to use Adadelta or Adam as your optimizer, which should adapt the learning rate for each parameter automatically.